# GNU bash dump-po-strings option

Tags: bash, arguments, gnu

in GNU bash manual reference (section 6.1 : Invoking bash) there are some option, two of them are as follows:

> --dump-po-strings A list of all double-quoted strings preceded by ‘$’ is printed on the standard output in the GNU gettext PO (portable
> object) file format. Equivalent to -D except for the output format.
>
> --dump-strings Equivalent to -D.

But I don't understand the meaning of them. I also search about them, unfortunatly I didn't find an example.

Can anybody explain them with an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $"text"
```

`--dump-po-strings` outputs format for creating translations. https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html

```
$ bash --dump-po-strings script.sh
#: script.sh:2
msgid "text"
msgstr ""
```

`--dump-strings` just outputs the strings inside `$"this"`.

```
$ bash --dump-strings script.sh
"text"
```